# Deleting image from slider doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working with [react-native-image-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider) .Slider is working perfect with array of images.I want to delete particular image while sliding at particular index.Suppose after sliding multiple images ,I am at index 6 and now i want to delete that image which is available at index 6.When i am using javascript splice method to delete and setting state with updated array after delete ,I am not able to see anything in slider.Can anyone help me out here.

Thank you

My Component delete function code:-

```
var newArray=[];
newArray=
this.state.imageFlatlist.splice(index, 1) &&  this.state.imageFlatlist;
    this.setState({
                imageFlatlist : newArray,
                isImageDeleted:true

    })
```

My render code:-

```
<ImageSlider images={this.state.imageFlatlist} onPositionChanged={position => 
     this._currentImagePosition(position)} style={{ flex: 1, }}
```

This is plugin code:-

```
_move(index) {
        console.log("movein to index:- " ,index);
        const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        const to = index * -width;
        if (!this.state.scrolling) {
            return;
        }
        Animated.spring(this.state.left, {toValue: to, friction: 10, tension: 50}).start();
        if (this.state.timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
        }
        this.setState({position: index, timeout: setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({scrolling: false, timeout: null});
            if (this.props.onPositionChanged) {
                this.props.onPositionChanged(index);
            }
        }, 500)});
    }

    _getPosition() {
        if (typeof this.props.position === 'number') {
            return this.props.position;
        }
        return this.state.position;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (props.position !== undefined) {
            this.setState({scrolling: true});
            this._move(props.position);
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        alert("Hey");
        const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

        if (typeof this.props.position === 'number') {
            this.state.left.setValue(-(width * this.props.position));
        }

        let release = (e, gestureState) => {
            const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
            const relativeDistance = gestureState.dx / width;
            const vx = gestureState.vx;
            let change = 0;
            console.log("relative Distance:- " , relativeDistance);
            console.log("**VX**" , vx);

            if (relativeDistance < -0.5 || (relativeDistance < 0 && vx <= 0.5)) {
                change = 1;
            } else if (relativeDistance > 0.5 || (relativeDistance > 0 && vx >= 0.5)) {
                change = -1;
            }
            const position = this._getPosition();
            console.log("Position:-   " , position);
            if (position === 0 && change === -1) {
                change = 0;
            } else if (position + change >= this.props.images.length) {

                change = (this.props.images.length) - (position + change);
            }
            this._move(position + change);
            return true;
        };

        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > 5,
            onPanResponderRelease: release,
            onPanResponderTerminate: release,
            onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {

                const dx = gestureState.dx;
                const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
                const position = this._getPosition();
                let left = -(position * width) + Math.round(dx);
                if (left > 0) {
                    left = Math.sin(left / width) * (width / 2);
                } else if (left < -(width * (this.props.images.length - 1))) {
                    const diff = left + (width * (this.props.images.length - 1));
                    left = Math.sin(diff / width) * (width / 2) - (width * (this.props.images.length - 1));
                }
                this.state.left.setValue(left);
                if (!this.state.scrolling) {
                    this.setState({scrolling: true});
                }
            },
            onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => true
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.state.timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const customStyles = this.props.style ? this.props.style : {};
        const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        const height = this.props.height || this.state.height;
        const position = this._getPosition();

        return (<View>
            <Animated.View
                style={[styles.container, customStyles, {height: height, width: width * this.props.images.length, transform: [{translateX: this.state.left}]}]}
                {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
                    {this.props.images.map((image, index) => {
                    console.log("image in lib ***" , this.props.images);
                    console.log("**lib index***"  ,  index);

                        const imageComponent = <Image
                                                key={index}
                                                source={{uri: image}}
                                                style={{height: position === index || this.state.scrolling ? height : 0, width}}
                                              />;
                    return imageComponent;


                    })}
            </Animated.View>
            {/* <View style={styles.buttons}>
                {this.props.images.map((image, index) => {
                    return (<TouchableHighlight
                        key={index}
                        underlayColor="#ccc"
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({scrolling: true});
                            return this._move(index);
                        }}
                        style={[styles.button, position === index && styles.buttonSelected]}>
                            <View></View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>);
                })}
            </View> */}
        </View>);
    }
```

Comment: You're not using the slice method in your code, you're using the splice method. Is this what you intend? Please update you question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry... i am using splice method...please tell me where i am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line in the slider code: 
`{this.props.images.map((image, index) => ...` It seems that images are not meant to be updated dynamically because in React props do not change, state is used for this occasion. I'd recommend you rewrite the code by simply adding `images` property in the state

```
export default class ImageSlider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            images: [], // <-----------
            position: 0,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').width * (4 / 9),
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            scrolling: false,
        };
    }
    ...
```

then adding this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   if(nextProps.images){
      this.setState(() => ({images: nextProps.images}))
   }
}
```

and finally use them in render like so

```
{this.state.images.map((image, index) => ...
```

### Edit

How to immutably splice an array:

at the top `import _ from "lodash"` then

```
const newArray = _.remove(this.state.imageFlatlist, (image, i) => i == index);
```

Comment: Still getting blank ..its updating state in componentWillReceiveProps (checked by putting alert ) but view is not updating..

Comment: Did you replace this.props.images in all places? I see it's used twice in the render method

Comment: I just noticed that you directly mutate this.state in your component. Don't do it, instead of splice method you can use https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove .

Comment: Updated the answer